# subsetting more than one ccle sample

Tags: r, rna-seq, subset

I'm working with the CCLE dataset and I'm trying to subset the data to just 3 cell lines of interest but not sure how to it.

Currently, I have been subsetting one by one but is there an easier way?

```
ccle_panc <- ccle_dataset$data[ , ccle_dataset$colAnnotation$SAMPLE_NAME=="KP4", "", ""]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to write R code, array references can use boolean values, and `in` is useful when you want to select from more than one value:

```
ccle_panc <- ccle_dataset$data[ , ccle_dataset$colAnnotation$SAMPLE_NAME %in% c("KP4", "DC1", "DC2")]
```

You can find more information about vector and array subsetting with boolean and numerical values here:

https://datacarpentry.org/R-ecology-lesson/01-intro-to-r.html#Subsetting_vectors

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a dataframe/tibble situation; you can also use the tidyverse approach and the comment from @gringer:

```
ccle_dataset$data %>%
filter(SAMPLE_NAME %in% c("KP4", "DC1", "DC2"))
```